# How to join tokenized words back together in a column in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with previously tokenized words that look like below. Replication code:

```
df <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "2","3"),
                  text = c("['I', 'like', 'apple']", "['we', 'go', 'swimming']", "['ask', 'questions']")
                  )
```

:

```
id   text
1   ["I", "like", "apple"]
2   ["we", "go", "swimming"]
3   ["ask", "questions"]
```

The original data frame was obtained in Python after preprocessing (including tokenizing) raw text data.
I'd like to merge these tokens back into a sentence so it would look like below

```
id   text
1   I like apple
2   we go swimming
3   ask questions
```

I tried using the paste() function `df$text_new<-paste(df$text, sep = " ")`, but it failed to work, still returning the same result.

Comment: Please provide the `dput()` for your sample input data. It's unclear exactly how data is stored in the text column. Do you have a nested list column? Or was the value coerced to a string? I'm not sure I've seen R display data quite like what you've shown before. What exactly did your attempt to use `paste()` look like?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `separate()` then `unite()` them with tidyr. You will have to provide a character vector long enough for each word in the longest sentence with `into =`  -- I used `letters` to get 26 -- and then refer to the first and last (`a:z`).

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame (id  = c("1", "2","3"),
                  text = c("['I', 'like', 'apple']", "['we', 'go', 'swimming']", "['ask', 'questions']"))

df %>% 
  separate(text, into = letters, fill = "right") %>% 
  unite(text, a:z, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE)

#>   id            text
#> 1  1    I like apple 
#> 2  2  we go swimming 
#> 3  3   ask questions
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>